# jquery plugin not working on html page, but not in site.master?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using a jQuery Banner Rotator plugin, and have it working fine on an html page. However, when I copy it accross to my site.master I get a javascript error saying "Object does not support property or method "allinone_bannerrotator".

The head sections of both docs are the same:

```
<head>
<title></title>
<!--[if !IE 7]>
    <style type="text/css">
        #wrap {display:table;height:100%}
    </style>
<![endif]-->
<link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="Styles/allinone_bannerRotator.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/allinone_bannerRotator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {

        $('#allinone_bannerRotator_classic').allinone_bannerRotator({
            skin: 'classic',
            width: 751,
            height: 229,
            thumbsFolder: 'images/classic/thumbs'
        });


    });
</script>
```

except that the site.master has the runat="server" tag, and a content placeholder in it:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

This is the code for the banner:

```
<div id="allinone_bannerRotator_classic" style="display: none; margin: 0px">
                            <!-- IMAGES -->
                            <img src="images/classic/banner1.png" alt="" data-text-id="#allinone_bannerRotator_photoText1" />
                            <img src="images/classic/banner2.png" alt="" data-text-id="#allinone_bannerRotator_photoText2" />
                            <img src="images/classic/banner3.png" alt="" data-text-id="#allinone_bannerRotator_photoText3" />
                            <img src="images/classic/banner4.png" alt="" data-text-id="#allinone_bannerRotator_photoText4" />
                            <!-- TEXTS -->
                            <div id="allinone_bannerRotator_photoText1" class="allinone_bannerRotator_texts">
                                <div class="allinone_bannerRotator_text_line textElement12_attractive" data-initial-left="50"
                                    data-initial-top="10" data-final-left="50" data-final-top="40" data-duration="0.5"
                                    data-fade-start="0" data-delay="0">
                                    Broadoak students love to
                                </div>
                                <div class="allinone_bannerRotator_text_line textElement11_attractive" data-initial-left="50"
                                    data-initial-top="10" data-final-left="50" data-final-top="70" data-duration="0.5"
                                    data-fade-start="0" data-delay="0.3">
                                    get stuck in</div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="allinone_bannerRotator_photoText2" class="allinone_bannerRotator_texts">
                                <div class="allinone_bannerRotator_text_line textElement12_attractive" data-initial-left="550"
                                    data-initial-top="60" data-final-left="350" data-final-top="60" data-duration="0.5"
                                    data-fade-start="0" data-delay="0">
                                    16 transition effects<br />
                                    for images</div>
                                <div class="allinone_bannerRotator_text_line textElement12_attractive" data-initial-left="550"
                                    data-initial-top="125" data-final-left="350" data-final-top="125" data-duration="0.5"
                                    data-fade-start="0" data-delay="0.3">
                                    optional can set the transition<br />
                                    for each image</div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="allinone_bannerRotator_photoText3" class="allinone_bannerRotator_texts">
                                <div class="allinone_bannerRotator_text_line textElement11_attractive" data-initial-left="480"
                                    data-initial-top="60" data-final-left="50" data-final-top="60" data-duration="0.5"
                                    data-fade-start="0" data-delay="0">
                                    Animated text from any direction</div>
                                <div class="allinone_bannerRotator_text_line textElement12_attractive" data-initial-left="0"
                                    data-initial-top="75" data-final-left="50" data-final-top="75" data-duration="0.5"
                                    data-fade-start="0" data-delay="0.3">
                                    top, bottom, left and right</div>
                                <div class="allinone_bannerRotator_text_line textElement11_attractive" data-initial-left="50"
                                    data-initial-top="250" data-final-left="50" data-final-top="110" data-duration="1"
                                    data-fade-start="0" data-delay="0.5">
                                    Any color, CSS and HTML formated</div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="allinone_bannerRotator_photoText4" class="allinone_bannerRotator_texts">
                                <div class="allinone_bannerRotator_text_line textElement12_attractive" data-initial-left="50"
                                    data-initial-top="0" data-final-left="50" data-final-top="260" data-duration="0.5"
                                    data-fade-start="0" data-delay="0">
                                    Line One is here</div>
                                <div class="allinone_bannerRotator_text_line textElement11_attractive" data-initial-left="50"
                                    data-initial-top="384" data-final-left="50" data-final-top="240" data-duration="0.5"
                                    data-fade-start="0" data-delay="0.3">
                                    Line Two over there</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Also, both the html test page, and the site master are in the same location in the site's structure, so I don't think this is a path issue.

Answer (score 0):

Oops. I had a second jQuery include in the page at a lower level than the site.master (e.g. on my default.aspx page)